# CSS link to act as button but inheriting behavior

Tags: css

I have link CSS define as:

```css
A
{
color: #315393; font-family: verdana; font-weight: 500; text-decoration:underline; font-size: 10px; 
}

A:Hover
{
color: #999999; font-family: verdana; font-weight: 500; text-decoration:none; font-size: 10px; 
}
```

However, there are a couple cases where I want a link to act like a button and for that I use bootstrap and give them the class of "btn btn-primary", but since they are still links it seems they are still using the above CSS. How can I exclude the link behavior CSS from these and is there a way to do it in-line to the link?

Comment: use `a:not(.btn.btn-primary) {...}`

Comment: Provide a minimalistic sample in JSFiddle that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[:not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/%3anot)** pseudo-class to exclude certain elements from the matched selector:

```css
a:not(.btn.btn-primary) {
    color: #315393; 
    font-family: verdana; 
    font-weight: 500; 
    text-decoration:underline; 
    font-size: 10px;
}

a:not(.btn.btn-primary):hover {
    color: #315393; 
    font-family: verdana; 
    font-weight: 500; 
    text-decoration:underline; 
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Comment: So would I put this on the existing code for A and A:hover or make new entries?

Comment: No above code will work for your anchors except those anchors with class `btn` and `btn-primary`